# Scheme string-append with double quotes

Tags: scheme

I am trying to append double quotes " to a string in Scheme, but when I try it keeps display the backslash as well.

i.e. (string-append "\" "some-string" "\") returns \"some-string\"

How can I append the double quotes without displaying the backslash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> (string-append "\"" "quotes!" "\"")
"\"quotes!\""
> (displayln (string-append "\"" "quotes!" "\""))
"quotes!"
```

Note that there is a difference between printing and displaying.
The REPL prints values - and in the case of strings shows the backslashes.
In a program were `display` is used to display values to the user, the
backslash is not shown.